# Use new domain name on previously installed files of wordpress

Tags: installation

I have a question on wordpress. I had a wordpress site installed using other domain name previously, now that domain name no longer using and i am not going to renew, and the domain name i have already removed from my cpanel. I want host that site with a new domain name. What should i do for that? And how can i do to make it work?

Comment: Is your site still complete in a Wordpress install or do you want to move it to another installation?

Comment: I want to maintain all the content inside. Just want to change a new domain name for that installed files. Do you have any clue to do that?

Comment: Yes, you just have to point the domain name to the relevant directory in cpanel. In WordPress you have to change the domain in the general options section. You then probably will be kicked out of the installation. Login again and it should work.

Comment: Just one thing: if there are any hard coded internal links (in menus, posts and so on) you will have to adapt them manually. Or you would have to do a search and replace in the database. So, always use relative links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this. I suppose you have shared hosting package on that installation and that you "only" need to change your domain name.

So one solution would be to rename your hosting package to another domain. If your domain is now `somedomain.com`, and you want to transfer it to `someotherdomain.com`, you will rename your hosting package to it and point DNS for `someotherdomain.com` to this server where the files are located. Also you will need to change in wp settings Wordpress adress(URL) and Site Adress(URL). You change that also to link of your new `someotherdomain.com`. And that should be it in up to 48h when DNS do what it needs to do(usually faster).

The one minor problem with this kind of just "renaming" is that if you have a lot of media links (images, videos, etc) you will need to (in most cases) manually change it to new links.

To avoid that you can use (what I use, even if I just changing domain name) plugin called [DUPLICATOR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). So if you have shared hosting you can open new package for this domain and just tranfer files with duplicator and in this case the links will be automatically changed(I would recommend this for larger sites with much of media links etc), and also all the database links.

I hope this helps.

Regards